# type declaration python error

Tags: python, types

Hi am new to python found this code in one book and wanted to try it but line 4 says its an error "encountered type when expecting one of the following  and a list of brackets.  How to fix it?

```
#: arrays/PythonLists.py

aList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print type(aList) # <type 'list'>
print aList # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print aList[4] # 5   Basic list indexing
aList.append(6) # lists can be resized
aList += [7, 8] # Add a list to a list
print aList # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
aSlice = aList[2:4]
print aSlice # [3, 4]


class MyList(list): # Inherit from list
    # Define a method, 'this' pointer is explicit:
    def getReversed(self):
        reversed = self[:] # Copy list using slices
        reversed.reverse() # Built-in list method
        return reversed 

list2 = MyList(aList) # No 'new' needed for object creation
print type(list2) # <class '__main__.MyList'>
print list2.getReversed() # [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

#:~
```

Comment: Should work. What's the problem?

Comment: Works for me, are you sure this is exactly what you're trying to execute?

Comment: Are you sure this code does not work? I just copy-and-pasted and tried it out, it worked all fine.

Comment: I'm just seeing a plain syntax erro

Comment: Are you using a very (very, very) early version of Python?

Comment: I have downloaded newest stable version of Python from the python.org (3.2.2) and am using it with Eclipse PyDev plugin

Comment: @Solomon081: Eclipse (or the PyDev plugin) apparently tries to give more info. This made it somewhat harder to diagnose, because the error message was not a Python error message, and unknown to me (and probably many others).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Python 3.x, where `print` is a function and no longer a statement. The book is written for Python 2.x, where print still is a statement.

You fix it by using a version of Python that matches what the book describes, or get a book for a newer version of Python (3.x).

Your immediate problem can be solved by writing

```
print (type(aList))
```

Comment: Only thing that I can see, too.  Python 2.x interpreters are A-OK with the code as presented.